# How to navigate to a new page in Angular without changing the URL path, but pushing the new state in the location history?

Tags: angular

I know we can use `this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });` to navigate to a new view without reflecting the `/view` path into the URL.

But the issue here is that when I click the browser's back button, it goes back two states because in fact it doesn't retain the `/view` path in the history stack.

When I click the back button, I just want to go to the previous page I was before going to `/view` route, not two states back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done it in Angular 8 was:

`import { Location } from '@angular/common';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

then

`constructor(private location: Location, private router: Router) {}`

then, I pushed the current state into the history stack:

`this.location.go(this.location.path());`

just before navigating:

`this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you are going to /View and then navigating further but the stop at /View isn't in your history.

Since it is taking you back two states I'll make the assumption that the "skipLocationChange" skips pushing the current location onto the history stack. You can do this manual by calling history.pushState from you clientside JS.  Give this a try

```
let state = {  }
let title = ''
let url = 'View'

history.pushState(state, title, url)
```

State contains parameters in JSON form that you might want to pass. Title is ignored by most browsers. You may need to use windows.history.pushState and you will need to do this when you leave /View.

Hope this helps